# How to find the leaf-only parent nodes in an n-ary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

I'm trying to solve the following algorithm:

> You have an n-ary tree. Find all the nodes satisfying the following
>   condition:
>
> - the node has child node(s) but **all** of the child nodes are leafs (they have no children ). Return a list of leaf only parent nodes and
>     their depth in the tree.

So if I have the tree below, the only node satisfying the above condition is D, because it has descendants (E) but they don't have children.

```
  I am root!
     /\ \
    A B  F
      /\
     C  D
         \
         E
```

I'm trying to implement this in Java but pseudocode will also work for me.
I have the tree and node structures implemented here: [N-ary trees in Java](http://vivin.net/2010/01/30/generic-n-ary-tree-in-java/).

All I need is the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

1. start at root
2. while left son exists : go to left son
3. go back to father and check next son
4. if has no other sons : insert father to list
5. else insert father to list and go to step 2 but keep a depth counter and if found grandchildren : remove father from list
6. if finished all nodes : return list

   root
   / \ \
   A  B  F
   / \
   C  D
     \
      E

run example:

- go to A
- go back to root and insert root to list
- go to B
- go to C (remove root from potential because of counter)
- go back to B and add B to list
- go to D
- go to E (remove B from potential because of counter)
- go back to D and insert to list
- go back to B
- go back to root
- go to F (don't insert root because root was already inserted [and removed]
- return list which has only D

To make this work you should have a counter running for the node you are checking (to see if grandchildren exist) and also you should have a way of knowing if a node has been removed from the list so you would not insert it again (I didn't explicitly write it but I used 2 list - 1 for potentials and 1 for final)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it. Here's the solution I've reached. I'm sure there are better solutions though - you're welcome to correct me.

```
// kick off the recursion
public Map<Integer, Integer> findLeafOnlyParents(GenericTree<Integer> tree){
        Map<Integer, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

    // start search from the root
        traverseWithDepth(tree.getRoot(), resultMap, 0);

        return resultMap;
    } 


private void traverseWithDepth(GenericTreeNode<Integer> node,  Map<Integer, Integer> traversalResult, int depth) {

  // check if the current note in the traversal is parent Of leaf-only nodes
  if (isParentOfLeafOnly(node)){
    traversalResult.put(node.data, depth);
  }

  // check the node's children
  for(GenericTreeNode<Integer> child : node.getChildren()) {
    traverseWithDepth(child, traversalResult, depth + 1);
  }

}

// the main logic is here
private boolean isParentOfLeafOnly(GenericTreeNode<Integer> node){
  boolean isParentOfLeafOnly = false;

  // check if the node has children
  if(node.getChildren().size() > 0){

    // check the children of the node - they should not have children
    List<GenericTreeNode<Integer>> children = node.getChildren();
    boolean grandChildrenExist = false; 

    // for each child check if it has children of its own
    for(GenericTreeNode<Integer> child : children) {
      grandChildrenExist = child.getChildren().size() > 0;

      // once found note that the current node has grandchildren,
      // so we don't need to check the rest of the children of the node
      if (grandChildrenExist){
        break;
      }
     }

     // we need only the parents who don't have great children
    isParentOfLeafOnly = !grandChildrenExist;
  }
  return isParentOfLeafOnly;
}
```